# Sorting list of data after conversion from string to date

Tags: java

I have below DTO details

```
public class CreditDetailDTO {

    private String sectionType;

    private BigDecimal totalAmount;

    private List<SectionDetailsDTO> sectionDetails;

}

public class SectionDetailsDTO {
    private String startDate;

    private String expiryDate;

    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

I need to sorting sectionDetails by start date. I have use below code for sorting

```
creditDetailsDTO.getSectionDetails().sort(Comparator.comparing(SectionDetailsDTO::getStartDate));
```

> As you can see that `getStartDate` is string but what I need, First I
>   need to convert `getStartDate` into `date` and then based on the date
>   sort the data

Sample Date format : 15-07-2019:11:00:00

Comment: Convert it into `java.time.LocalDate` and then use its `compareTo(LocalDate o)` method.

Comment: Why do you use `String` instead of `LocalDate` or `Date` in the first place?

Comment: Can you give us an example of `startDate`?  If your'e using an ISO format, then sorting the strings themselves might already be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the date into `LocalDateTime` using `DateTimeFormatter`

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.parse("15-07-2019:11:10:20",f);
```

So the sorting code

```
creditDetailsDTO.getSectionDetails().stream()
    .sort(Comparator.comparing(dto -> LocalDateTime.parse(dto.getStartDate(), f)));
```

Comment: Above solution looks nice but facing below issue The method getStartDate() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: updated my code @ShiladittyaChakraborty But above code show you how to sort, you might need to collect them after sorting

Comment: Still same issue and also I think stream having sorted method

Comment: can you update the code in post, so that i can take a look @ShiladittyaChakraborty

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(your_String_pattern);
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(your_string_value);
Log.e("tag","Converted Date = "+date);
```

If your value and the pattern matches, it gives you the date. After that you can do your required operations on that date.(Make sure you put some validations for string_date_value).